# Yii2 when used transactions for multi step registration then on the step back how to retrive data

Tags: transactions, yii2

**Current Implementation**

Currently I am using multi step registration and i have total 3 steps for the same.

Last step is confirm all data entered and then submit.

Now I am using transaction on the very beginning of step 1 like :

```
$transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
```

if execution fails at any point I am using

```
$transaction->rollBack();
```

to rollback all the entries from database

Now if everything is executed well and in the last step user confirms entered data and submit i save all data in db like :

```
$transaction->commit();
```

**Issue**

Now as I am using multi step registration if anytime user want to go back to previous step, then **how to retrieve filled data** ???

We can not retrieve data from table as still we haven't store anything into db until last commit statement.

**Current Solution**

One solution is that is to use session to store temporary data but I am looking for any other way

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a new action for each of the steps (and one table called 'registration' i.e.) then for each action you can pass registration `id`, and load fields depending on step number.
So, let's consider you have a registration form with `name`, `surname`, `age`, `gender` fields, and in Step-1 you fill `name`, `surname`, and in Step 2 fill `age` and `gender`.. Your model will look like follow:

```
class Registration extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_STEP1 = 'step1';
    const SCENARIO_STEP2 = 'step2';

    public function scenarios()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_STEP1 => ['name', 'surname'],
            self::SCENARIO_STEP2 => ['age', 'gender'],
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        ... your validation for fields...
```

...

Note that Scenarios are important here to enable validation for some exact fields in exact step (More about scenarios you can read from [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios))

And the action for your first step will look this way:

```
public function actionStep1()
{
    $model = new Registration();
    $model->setScenario(Registration::SCENARIO_STEP1);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['step-2', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('step-1', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And in your `step-1` view you have fields `name` and `surname` that you need to fill, and where validation will work for them only as listed in `scenarios()` method). Then in second step action the code will look like this:

```
public function actionStep2($id)
{
    $model = Order::findOne($id);
    $model->setScenario(Order::SCENARIO_STEP2);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['finish', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('step-2', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

.. As you can see, in second step we pass `id` of already existing Registration model, and continue filling its attributes. Depending on how much steps you have, you can redirect from second step to the third one, or show finish message and do some other logic that you need..

I think you have a little bit wrong idea about how transactions are used, because transaction is the way how rows in DB are saved (preventing these rows from being changed somewhere else, when the change itself is being proceeded..)

Another approach of making a multi step registration is to include all steps in single page, and show/hide needed fields depending on your stage (Using JQuery for example). I remember answering this kind of question already, but cannot find the link.. If I succeed, I'll definitely update my answer..

Hope my answer was helpful

Comment: As per my knowledge if you have used transactions then it will not create any record in db until you commit it using  $transaction->commit();

Comment: Now the reason behind use of transaction is want to avoid any non completed data in db, like if someone lefts the registration in between.

Comment: Yeah, but transaction is usually used for a short period of time. For example, you have a bank account. Consider that you pay for some service, and at the same moment someone is transferring some money to you (he cannot do that until you commit your transaction). I mean transaction is proceeded in one script, so that you cannot pass it to another action... (it'll simple be rolled back)

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep as much of your solution and not user session storage, then I would say to make do the validation of each step using an ajax request.

To more detail,

- user enters a url eg user/register#step1
- fills in the form
- clicks next step
- an AJAX request is sent to validate the data sent
- if validation succeeds, then go to step 2 eg "user/register#step2"
- Step 1 form is hidden, step 2 form is shown using javascript.
- If validation fails, show the messages and stay to the current step.

This way you can go back to the previous step and have the form filled, since no reload of the page was done. (Use url hash for the steps)

In each step, except the last one, you can use:

```
$transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
```

Save your model(s).

At the end roll back all the changes.(both for success and fail)

```
$transaction->rollBack();
```

This way you can make sure your data can be saved on the database(maybe your database have restrictions that are not defined in the rules) without actual saving anything.

At the last step, you collect all the data from all steps:

```
$transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
```

Save your model(s) and commit changes if validated.

```
$transaction->commit();
```